# Spring: IdempotentReceiverInterceptor can only be used on MessageHandlers?

Tags: java, spring-integration

I'm trying to use the IdempotentReceiverInterceptor to prevent my integration flow from emitting messages it has already produced. However, it seems that IdempotentReceiverInterceptor#invoke only wants components that extend MessageHandler (to a degree) or have a method called "handleMessage" who's first argument is a Message. I want to deduplicate the message and if it falls through, perform some additional processing.

My questions is two fold:

- Is there a reason why this advice shouldn't be allowed on any
  component; Transformer, GenericHandler, etc.?
- Because its only allowed to run on MessageHandler(s) or anything that has a handleMessage method, I tried using the AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler (because i need to do additional processing), but that does not work either.

I feel like I'm misunderstanding the proper use of the IdempotentReceiverInterceptor, that i should be able to use it on almost any component, but the implementation doesn't seem to agree with me. Am I incorrect on how it should be used or am I using it wrong? I know i could probably just throw the MetadataStoreSelector in the flow as a filter, but am trying to do things as recommended by SI.

Any help is appreciated. Here is an example flow that i would have expected to work.

```
return IntegrationFlows
    .from(messageProducer)
    .<String, UUID>transform(s -> UUID.fromString(s))
    .claimCheckOut(messageStore)
    .handle(
        new AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler() {

          @Override
          protected Object handleRequestMessage(final Message<?> requestMessage) {
            return requestMessage;
          }

        },
        spec -> {
          spec.advice(idempotentReceiverInterceptor);
        })
    // do some more stuff
    .transform(transformer)
    .handle(loggingHandler)
    .get();
```

and here is the log message showing that it didnt

```
This advice org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.IdempotentReceiverInterceptor can only be used for MessageHandlers; an attempt to advise method 'toString' in 'org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler$AdvisedRequestHandler' is ignored
```

**EDIT:** for those that come here looking a solution, this is pretty much what i ended up doing anyways

```
return IntegrationFlows
    .from(messageProducer)
    .<String, UUID>transform(s -> UUID.fromString(s))
    .claimCheckOut(messageStore)
    .filter(metadataStoreSelector)
    // do some more stuff
    .transform(transformer)
    .handle(loggingHandler)
    .get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#idempotent-receiver):

> This is an AOP Advice, which is applied to the `MessageHandler.handleMessage()` method and can filter a request message or mark it as a duplicate, according to its configuration.

And the source code says:

```
boolean isMessageHandler = invocationThis != null && invocationThis instanceof MessageHandler;
boolean isMessageMethod = method.getName().equals("handleMessage")
        && (arguments.length == 1 && arguments[0] instanceof Message);
```

In other words only `MessageHandler` implementations can be affected with the `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor`.

That's one.

You worry about `Transformer`, `GenericHandler` for nothing. The Framework ends up with the particular `MessageHandler` wrapping anyway, e.g. `ServiceActivatingHandler`, `MessageTransformingHandler` etc. All of that just because it is like contract in the Spring Integration: `channel -> endpoint -> messageHandler`.

That's two.

Since the main premise of `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor` is to apply logic exactly to the consumer endpoint (see its documentation), you can't use it from the  `spec.advice()`, because that is exactly for the `handleRequestMessage()`, as you expected. But that doesn't work for `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor`.

Yeah... Unfortunately there is no so easy way to utilize it via Java DSL style. Although you can distinguish your flow via message channels and extract `@ServiceActivator` (`@Transformer`) together with the `@IdempotentReceiver` into separate `@Service`, until we figure out the solution for "raw" Java config.

Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) ticket on the matter. I think `ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean` should distinguish the `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor` from all other in the `advice` and apply it properly to the `handleMessage` finally. So, your expected config will work.

Thank you for spotting that out!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did not realize that it wouldn't work properly when used with DSL based flow configuration. I created Jira INT-4064

Comment: Also see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/92